# Automate editing of column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I need to automate the editing of the column headings of a spreadsheet (the top row -- A1, B1 etc). The goal is to retain the first token (having the form KI_xxxxxx) and to remove the bracketed terms (strings bracketed by parentheses (`()`) or square brackets (`[]`)).

Here are some before-and-after examples: on the left of the arrow (`->`) is an example before it has been edited, and on the right of the arrow is the corresponding desired result:

1. KI_Categories (Commodities Provided) [UniqueName] -> KI_Categories
2. KI_2256522 (Unique TAX ID (US)) -> KI_2256522
3. KI_2408691 (Company VAT Number (EUROPE)) -> KI_2408691

Comment: Use rng.Replace What:="KI_", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, Iterate this for all the value you want to remove

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear regarding which programming language you use. `macro` alone is a rather generic tag. Furthermore, it usually helps when you show what you have tried so far and mention where the problem lies.

Comment: Sorry guys I have this in excel, I have to be honest not too sure where to start! I am looking for a macro I can run in excel please. Silva and kazemakase thansk for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
    Sub RemoveJunk()
     Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = Range("A1").EntireRow 'Assuming headings are in Row1

     For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If (cell.Value = "") Then Exit For
        cell.Value = (Split(cell, "(")(0))
     Next


    End Sub
```

Comment: SILVA youa re amazing thank you so very much. Your comments are invaluable, I owe youa  beer my friend this works a charm :)

Comment: Actually Silva, I am a doughnut. I have done this the wrong way round! I actually need this to look like:-

Comment: 1.
KI_Categories (Commodities Provided) [UniqueName] - KI_Categories 

 2.
KI_2256522 (Unique TAX ID (US)) - KI_2256522

 3.
KI_2408691 (Company VAT Number (EUROPE)) - KI_2408691

Comment: Can be done. Modify your question also, will update my code soon

Comment: Thanks Silva modified my friend, you are a diamond :)

Comment: Of course this works Silva, you are the Man!! Thank you so very much I really appreciate your help friend. Have a good day wherever in the world you are :)

Comment: Thank you and wish you the same. Please mark the question as answered so that this can be a ready to use solution for others

Comment: Done, thanks again my friend :) The baby int he pic is cute, congratulations :)